# There is a duplicate line showed when calling a __init__ in Python script

Tags: python, function, class, object

I saw a very strange phenomenon when calling a class in Python:
    I want to see "Base created now" on the screen. However I saw two lines,  which are exactly the same. This is very strange to me.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base created now"

test1=Base()
test1.__init__()
```

The result on the screen:

```
Base created now
Base created now
```

So I did another experiment: I changed the "init" to "print_test":

```
class Base(object):
    def print_test(self):
        print "Base created now"

test1=Base()
test1.print_test()
```

The result on the screen:

```
Base created now
```

Do you know why the 1st script has two same lines, and the 2nd only has one line?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__init__()` is your constructor method, it always gets called when creating new instances

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base created now"

test1=Base()   # this creates a new instance and calls __init__()
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I have it interpreted as:   The __init__ is a special function. Whenever I creats a new instance and call this __init__ function, it will automatically "duplicate" all the content in this function. Am I correct?

Comment: In almost all cases you simply never call `__init__()` yourself.

Comment: Thanks. To avoid the unnecessary dumping message on screen, I changed the "__init__" content: removed the "print" action, and add some dummy(redundant) content into it. Then I wrote another new function, parallel with "__init__", which is a print function. Now if I call the new print function, it only has one line on screen. Great! :)